# Why research on time series always use data with the same (instead of lower) level of precision to make forecast?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Suppose there is a dataset with data points for every 1 second:

```
x1, x2, ..., x15
```

and suppose the following are the average values for every 5 seconds:

```
y1 = (x1 + x2 + ... + x5) / 5
y2 = (x6 + x7 + ... + x10) / 5
y3 = (x11 + x12 + ... + x15) / 5
```

To forecast the value of `y3`, as far as I know it's very common to use `y1` and `y2` to predict, instead of using `x1, x2, ..., x10`. What is the reason for this? Is it because of high correlation (values should be all averages), or difficulty of using raw data (e.g. due to noise), or any other reason?

I want to ask this question because I thought that using more information (from raw data before averaging) would provide higher forecasting accuracy.

Comment: what type of time series are you are referring to. I have not seen this.